# Adding a new column to a list of dataframes, but only select one line of a vector

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames and I'm trying to add a corresponding element of a vector as value for a new variable across all observations to each data frame of the list.

My question would be: Is there some kind of "index" that keeps track in which step the lapply function is right now? I wasn't able to find anything on this, but it would solve my problem I believe because I wouldn't need a loop and could just use `timevar <- time[magic.index]` I think the example makes a lot clearer what I mean.

```
#list of data frames
df1 <- data.frame("Var1" = c(1:10))
df2 <- data.frame("Var1" = c(1:10),"Var2" = c(1:10))
df3 <- data.frame("Var1" = c(1:10),"Var2" = c(1:10),"Var3" = c(1:10))
dfs <- list(df1,df3,df2)

time <- c(1,2,1)

#this is what I want to do with lapply
lapply(dfs, function(x) within(x, timevar <- 1))

dfs2 <- for (i in seq_along(dfs)){
 lapply(dfs, function(x) within(x, timevar <- time))
}

#this is what the result should look like
dfs[[1]] <- within(dfs[[1]], timevar <- 1)
dfs[[2]] <- within(dfs[[2]], timevar <- 2)
dfs[[3]] <- within(dfs[[3]], timevar <- 1)
dfs
```

Comment: Note that `lapply()` *is* a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to create a 'timevar' column by `cbind`ing the corresponding `list` element in 'dfs' with the element in 'time' vector.

```
Map(cbind, dfs, timevar = time)
#[[1]]
#   Var1 timevar
#1     1       1
#2     2       1
#3     3       1
#4     4       1
#5     5       1
#6     6       1
#7     7       1
#8     8       1
#9     9       1
#10   10       1

#[[2]]
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 timevar
#1     1    1    1       2
#2     2    2    2       2
#3     3    3    3       2
#4     4    4    4       2
#5     5    5    5       2
#6     6    6    6       2
#7     7    7    7       2
#8     8    8    8       2
#9     9    9    9       2
#10   10   10   10       2

#[[3]]
#   Var1 Var2 timevar
#1     1    1       1
#2     2    2       1
#3     3    3       1
#4     4    4       1
#5     5    5       1
#6     6    6       1
#7     7    7       1
#8     8    8       1
#9     9    9       1
#10   10   10       1
```

---

If we are using `hadleyverse` , the `map2` from `purrr` can be useful as well

```
library(purrr)
dfs %>% 
    map2(time, ~cbind(.x, timevar=.y))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm in my example aswell, but I also get `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 21, 23` I'm really certain it stems from this `> str(time)
'data.frame': 23 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ time: int  2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
> str(dfs[[1]])
'data.frame': 21 obs. of  188 variables:` But from my understanding they don't have to be of the same length do they?

Comment: @Susu Do you have the `length` of 'dfs' equal to the length of 'time'.  Looks like you have 'time' as a data.farme'  so use `Map(cbind, dfs, timevar = time$time)`

Comment: Great, you got it! `length(time)` was indeed 1. After using `t(time)` it worked! Thank you so much! Edit: `time$time works` aswell.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
lapply(seq_len(length(dfs)),function(t) cbind(dfs[[t]],time[t]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this worked great in the example. Hower in my real data I get `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 21, 23` whereas `23` is the `length of time` and `21` is the `number of observations in my first data frame`. I'm not really sure though why I get that error, it doesn't make sense to me since the value taken from time is just a number anyways? (I tried to edit the example to match my data better, but your solution still works there). Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for helping out, aswell! Akrun solved it already, so no need for you to think about it.